# Page Speed API - Differentiate Mobile and Desktop

Tags: pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals, google-pagespeed-insights-api

For the same url, Google's PageSpeed Insights gives different scores on Mobile and Desktop. I am trying to understand how to **differentiate the device level data while using the PageSpeed Insights API call**.
Or does the PageSpeed Insights API call give results at an overall level?
Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

The [`strategy`](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rest/v5/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#Strategy) parameter of the PSI API is used to differentiate between desktop and mobile results. Note that when the parameter is omitted, `STRATEGY_UNSPECIFIED` defaults to desktop.

The PSI API docs have an API explorer that lets you run queries and see the results in a web UI. Here are a couple of examples:

[Desktop](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rest/v5/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed?apix_params=%7B%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%22%2C%22strategy%22%3A%22DESKTOP%22%7D&apix=true#Strategy):

```json
{
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "strategy": "DESKTOP"
}
```

[Mobile](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rest/v5/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed?apix_params=%7B%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%22%2C%22strategy%22%3A%22MOBILE%22%7D&apix=true#Strategy):

```json
{
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "strategy": "MOBILE"
}
```

If you only have the PSI API results and want to know whether it relates to desktop or mobile data, you can look at the the `lhr.lighthouseResult.configSettings.formFactor` property, which will be `'desktop'` or `'mobile'` (where the response object is the value `lhr`).

See the [`ConfigSettings`](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rest/v5/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#ConfigSettings) docs for more info on the `formFactor` field and other metadata about the results.